# Alternative background-color for sibling div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am running into an issue for this system I am creating. I have a total of four sibling div containers. They go like this in a normal desktop view:

*Blue Red Blue Red*

This works for 2/3 viewports to show the `background-color`'s as an alternate color. It works in the normal desktop mode and a 640px screen and below, but for my middle viewport 640-840px's, the screen shows the colors like this:

*Blue Red*

*Blue Red*

Which will make it very difficult to read. Basically I will need the divs' color to change in a pattern like this:

*Blue Red*

*Red Blue*

Is there a way I can accomplish this?

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}
.box-container {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
}
.blue-box, .red-box {
 height: 50%;
 width: 25%;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.blue-box {
 background-color: blue;
}
.red-box {
 background-color: red;
}
.blue-box:hover, .red-box:hover {
 background-color: purple;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.blue-box:hover .box-description, .red-box:hover .box-description {
 display: none;
}
.blue-box:hover .box-description-hover, .red-box:hover .box-description-hover {
 display: block;
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 padding-top: 20px;
}
.insideBoxWrap {
 padding: 50px 18%;
}
.box-title {
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 2.6em;
}
.box-description {
 padding-top: 15px;
 color: green;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}
.box-description-hover {
 display: none;
}
/*----------------------------------------------PHONE MEDIA QUERY 640--------------------------*/

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
 .box-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
 }
 .blue-box, .red-box {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
 }
 .blue-box:hover, .red-box:hover {
  height: 100%;
 }
 .blue-box:hover .box-description-hover, .red-box:hover .box-description-hover {
  display: block;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  padding-top: 20px;
 }
 .insideBoxWrap {
  padding: 30px 30px;
 }
 .box-title {
  font-size: 1.6em;
 }
 .box-description {
  padding-top: 5px;
  color: green;
  font-size: 1.1em;
 }
} 
/*----------------------------------------------PHONE MEDIA QUERY 641 - 840--------------------------*/

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width:840px) {
 .box-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
 .blue-box, .red-box {
  height: 33%;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="blue-box">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
      <div class="box-title">Box 1</div>
      <div class="box-description">Normal View</div>
      <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View</div>
    </div>
  </div><div class="red-box">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
      <div class="box-title">Box 2</div>
      <div class="box-description">Normal View</div>
      <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View</div>
    </div>
  </div><div class="blue-box">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
      <div class="box-title">Box 3</div>
      <div class="box-description">Normal View</div>
      <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View</div>
    </div>
  </div><div class="red-box">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
      <div class="box-title">Box 4</div>
      <div class="box-description">Normal View</div>
      <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this:

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/pen/dGWKXE?editors=110)**

```
.blue-box:nth-child(3){
    background-color:red;
 }
.red-box:nth-child(4){
   background-color:blue;
}
```

to the `@media screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width:840px)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="group">
  <div class="blue-box">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
      <div class="box-title">Box 1</div>
      <div class="box-description">Normal View</div>
      <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="red-box">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
      <div class="box-title">Box 2</div>
      <div class="box-description">Normal View</div>
      <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
  <div class="blue-box">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
      <div class="box-title">Box 3</div>
      <div class="box-description">Normal View</div>
      <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="red-box">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
      <div class="box-title">Box 4</div>
      <div class="box-description">Normal View</div>
      <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS as

```
/*----------------------------------------------PHONE MEDIA QUERY 641 - 840--------------------------*/

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width:840px) {
    .box-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .blue-box, .red-box {
        height: 33%;
        width: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .group:nth-child(even) .blue-box {
        background-color: red;
    }
    .group:nth-child(even) .red-box {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.